# Can't upgrade Rails 5.2.4.4. to 5.2.5

Tags: ruby-on-rails, bundler

I am trying to upgrade my project running on Rails 5.2.4.4 to 5.2.5. But when I change the Rails version to 5.2.5 in Gemfile and run `bundle update`, it bumps up the Rails version to 5.2.6 instead of 5.2.5. Can anybody guide me?

Here is my Gemfile:

```
source 'http://rubygems.org'
ruby "2.6.6"

# Bundle edge Rails instead: gem 'rails', github: 'rails/rails'
gem 'rails', '~> 5.2.5'
# Use postgresql as the database for Active Record
gem 'pg'
# Use Puma as the app server
gem 'puma'
# Rolling restart Puma worker processes
gem 'puma_worker_killer'
# Convert objects to json
gem 'active_model_serializers', '~> 0.10.10'
# Use Firebase Cloud Messaging
gem 'fcm'
# to interact with Google Cloud Storages
gem 'google-cloud-storage'
# Httparty for networking
gem 'httparty'
# twitter secure headers for extra security
gem 'secure_headers'
# use lograge for cleaning up logs
gem 'lograge'
# used for setting up CORS settings in controllers
gem 'rack-cors'
# redis + sidekiq for background jobs, and sinatra for monitoring
gem 'redis', '~> 4.0.2'
gem 'redis-namespace'
gem 'sidekiq'
gem 'sinatra', :require => false
# Use ActiveModel has_secure_password
gem 'bcrypt', '~> 3.1.7'
# Email support through Mailgun
gem 'mailgun-ruby', '~>1.1.6'
# Heroku platform API to enable dyno restarts
gem 'platform-api'
# to monitor object creation in Heroku
gem 'scout_apm'
# to monitor errors
gem "honeybadger", "~> 4.0"

group :development, :test do
  # Call 'byebug' anywhere in the code to stop execution and get a debugger console
  gem 'byebug', platform: :mri
  gem 'simplecov'
  gem 'capybara'
  gem 'cucumber-rails', :require => false
  gem 'rspec-rails'
  gem 'factory_bot'
  gem 'database_cleaner'
  gem 'rails-controller-testing'
  gem 'shoulda-matchers'
  gem 'webmock'
end

group :development do
  # Access an IRB console on exception pages or by using <%= console %> anywhere in the code.
  gem 'web-console'
  gem 'listen', '~> 3.0.5'
  # Spring speeds up development by keeping your application running in the background. Read more: https://github.com/rails/spring
  gem 'spring'
  gem 'spring-watcher-listen', '~> 2.0.0'
end

# Windows does not include zoneinfo files, so bundle the tzinfo-data gem
gem 'tzinfo-data'
```

Here is my Gemfile.lock:

```
GEM
  remote: http://rubygems.org/
  specs:
    actioncable (5.2.4.4)
      actionpack (= 5.2.4.4)
      nio4r (~> 2.0)
      websocket-driver (>= 0.6.1)
    actionmailer (5.2.4.4)
      actionpack (= 5.2.4.4)
      actionview (= 5.2.4.4)
      activejob (= 5.2.4.4)
      mail (~> 2.5, >= 2.5.4)
      rails-dom-testing (~> 2.0)
    actionpack (5.2.4.4)
      actionview (= 5.2.4.4)
      activesupport (= 5.2.4.4)
      rack (~> 2.0, >= 2.0.8)
      rack-test (>= 0.6.3)
      rails-dom-testing (~> 2.0)
      rails-html-sanitizer (~> 1.0, >= 1.0.2)
    actionview (5.2.4.4)
      activesupport (= 5.2.4.4)
      builder (~> 3.1)
      erubi (~> 1.4)
      rails-dom-testing (~> 2.0)
      rails-html-sanitizer (~> 1.0, >= 1.0.3)
    active_model_serializers (0.10.10)
      actionpack (>= 4.1, < 6.1)
      activemodel (>= 4.1, < 6.1)
      case_transform (>= 0.2)
      jsonapi-renderer (>= 0.1.1.beta1, < 0.3)
    activejob (5.2.4.4)
      activesupport (= 5.2.4.4)
      globalid (>= 0.3.6)
    activemodel (5.2.4.4)
      activesupport (= 5.2.4.4)
    activerecord (5.2.4.4)
      activemodel (= 5.2.4.4)
      activesupport (= 5.2.4.4)
      arel (>= 9.0)
    activestorage (5.2.4.4)
      actionpack (= 5.2.4.4)
      activerecord (= 5.2.4.4)
      marcel (~> 0.3.1)
    activesupport (5.2.4.4)
      concurrent-ruby (~> 1.0, >= 1.0.2)
      i18n (>= 0.7, < 2)
      minitest (~> 5.1)
      tzinfo (~> 1.1)
    addressable (2.7.0)
      public_suffix (>= 2.0.2, < 5.0)
    arel (9.0.0)
    ast (2.4.1)
    bcrypt (3.1.16)
    bindex (0.8.1)
    builder (3.2.4)
    byebug (11.1.3)
    capybara (3.33.0)
      addressable
      mini_mime (>= 0.1.3)
      nokogiri (~> 1.8)
      rack (>= 1.6.0)
      rack-test (>= 0.6.3)
      regexp_parser (~> 1.5)
      xpath (~> 3.2)
    case_transform (0.2)
      activesupport
    concurrent-ruby (1.1.7)
    connection_pool (2.2.3)
    crack (0.4.4)
    crass (1.0.6)
    cucumber (4.1.0)
      builder (~> 3.2, >= 3.2.3)
      cucumber-core (~> 7.1, >= 7.1.0)
      cucumber-create-meta (~> 1.0.0, >= 1.0.0)
      cucumber-cucumber-expressions (~> 10.1, >= 10.1.0)
      cucumber-gherkin (~> 14.0, >= 14.0.1)
      cucumber-html-formatter (~> 7.0, >= 7.0.0)
      cucumber-messages (~> 12.2, >= 12.2.0)
      cucumber-wire (~> 3.1, >= 3.1.0)
      diff-lcs (~> 1.3, >= 1.3, < 1.4)
      multi_test (~> 0.1, >= 0.1.2)
      sys-uname (~> 1.0, >= 1.0.2)
    cucumber-core (7.1.0)
      cucumber-gherkin (~> 14.0, >= 14.0.1)
      cucumber-messages (~> 12.2, >= 12.2.0)
      cucumber-tag-expressions (~> 2.0, >= 2.0.4)
    cucumber-create-meta (1.0.0)
      cucumber-messages (~> 12.2, >= 12.2.0)
      sys-uname (~> 1.2, >= 1.2.1)
    cucumber-cucumber-expressions (10.3.0)
    cucumber-gherkin (14.2.0)
      cucumber-messages (~> 12.4, >= 12.4.0)
    cucumber-html-formatter (7.2.0)
      cucumber-messages (~> 12.4, >= 12.4.0)
    cucumber-messages (12.4.0)
      protobuf-cucumber (~> 3.10, >= 3.10.8)
    cucumber-rails (2.1.0)
      capybara (>= 2.12, < 4)
      cucumber (>= 3.0.2, < 5)
      mime-types (>= 2.0, < 4)
      nokogiri (~> 1.8)
      rails (>= 4.2, < 7)
    cucumber-tag-expressions (2.0.4)
    cucumber-wire (3.1.0)
      cucumber-core (~> 7.1, >= 7.1.0)
      cucumber-cucumber-expressions (~> 10.1, >= 10.1.0)
      cucumber-messages (~> 12.2, >= 12.2.0)
    database_cleaner (1.8.5)
    declarative (0.0.20)
    declarative-option (0.1.0)
    diff-lcs (1.3)
    digest-crc (0.6.1)
      rake (~> 13.0)
    docile (1.3.2)
    domain_name (0.5.20190701)
      unf (>= 0.0.5, < 1.0.0)
    erubi (1.9.0)
    erubis (2.7.0)
    excon (0.76.0)
    factory_bot (6.1.0)
      activesupport (>= 5.0.0)
    faraday (1.0.1)
      multipart-post (>= 1.2, < 3)
    fcm (1.0.2)
      faraday (~> 1.0.0)
    ffi (1.13.1)
    globalid (0.4.2)
      activesupport (>= 4.2.0)
    google-api-client (0.50.0)
      addressable (~> 2.5, >= 2.5.1)
      googleauth (~> 0.9)
      httpclient (>= 2.8.1, < 3.0)
      mini_mime (~> 1.0)
      representable (~> 3.0)
      retriable (>= 2.0, < 4.0)
      rexml
      signet (~> 0.12)
    google-cloud-core (1.5.0)
      google-cloud-env (~> 1.0)
      google-cloud-errors (~> 1.0)
    google-cloud-env (1.4.0)
      faraday (>= 0.17.3, < 2.0)
    google-cloud-errors (1.0.1)
    google-cloud-storage (1.29.1)
      addressable (~> 2.5)
      digest-crc (~> 0.4)
      google-api-client (~> 0.33)
      google-cloud-core (~> 1.2)
      googleauth (~> 0.9)
      mini_mime (~> 1.0)
    googleauth (0.14.0)
      faraday (>= 0.17.3, < 2.0)
      jwt (>= 1.4, < 3.0)
      memoist (~> 0.16)
      multi_json (~> 1.11)
      os (>= 0.9, < 2.0)
      signet (~> 0.14)
    hashdiff (1.0.1)
    heroics (0.1.1)
      erubis (~> 2.0)
      excon
      moneta
      multi_json (>= 1.9.2)
    honeybadger (4.9.0)
    http-cookie (1.0.3)
      domain_name (~> 0.5)
    httparty (0.18.1)
      mime-types (~> 3.0)
      multi_xml (>= 0.5.2)
    httpclient (2.8.3)
    i18n (1.8.5)
      concurrent-ruby (~> 1.0)
    jsonapi-renderer (0.2.2)
    jwt (2.2.2)
    listen (3.0.8)
      rb-fsevent (~> 0.9, >= 0.9.4)
      rb-inotify (~> 0.9, >= 0.9.7)
    lograge (0.11.2)
      actionpack (>= 4)
      activesupport (>= 4)
      railties (>= 4)
      request_store (~> 1.0)
    loofah (2.7.0)
      crass (~> 1.0.2)
      nokogiri (>= 1.5.9)
    mail (2.7.1)
      mini_mime (>= 0.1.1)
    mailgun-ruby (1.1.11)
      rest-client (~> 2.0.2)
    marcel (0.3.3)
      mimemagic (~> 0.3.2)
    memoist (0.16.2)
    method_source (1.0.0)
    middleware (0.1.0)
    mime-types (3.3.1)
      mime-types-data (~> 3.2015)
    mime-types-data (3.2020.0512)
    mimemagic (0.3.5)
    mini_mime (1.0.2)
    mini_portile2 (2.4.0)
    minitest (5.14.2)
    moneta (1.0.0)
    multi_json (1.15.0)
    multi_test (0.1.2)
    multi_xml (0.6.0)
    multipart-post (2.1.1)
    mustermann (1.1.1)
      ruby2_keywords (~> 0.0.1)
    netrc (0.11.0)
    nio4r (2.5.4)
    nokogiri (1.10.10)
      mini_portile2 (~> 2.4.0)
    os (1.1.1)
    parser (3.0.0.0)
      ast (~> 2.4.1)
    pg (1.2.3)
    platform-api (3.0.0)
      heroics (~> 0.1.1)
      moneta (~> 1.0.0)
      rate_throttle_client (~> 0.1.0)
    protobuf-cucumber (3.10.8)
      activesupport (>= 3.2)
      middleware
      thor
      thread_safe
    public_suffix (4.0.6)
    puma (5.0.0)
      nio4r (~> 2.0)
    rack (2.2.3)
    rack-cors (1.1.1)
      rack (>= 2.0.0)
    rack-protection (2.1.0)
      rack
    rack-test (1.1.0)
      rack (>= 1.0, < 3)
    rails (5.2.4.4)
      actioncable (= 5.2.4.4)
      actionmailer (= 5.2.4.4)
      actionpack (= 5.2.4.4)
      actionview (= 5.2.4.4)
      activejob (= 5.2.4.4)
      activemodel (= 5.2.4.4)
      activerecord (= 5.2.4.4)
      activestorage (= 5.2.4.4)
      activesupport (= 5.2.4.4)
      bundler (>= 1.3.0)
      railties (= 5.2.4.4)
      sprockets-rails (>= 2.0.0)
    rails-controller-testing (1.0.5)
      actionpack (>= 5.0.1.rc1)
      actionview (>= 5.0.1.rc1)
      activesupport (>= 5.0.1.rc1)
    rails-dom-testing (2.0.3)
      activesupport (>= 4.2.0)
      nokogiri (>= 1.6)
    rails-html-sanitizer (1.3.0)
      loofah (~> 2.3)
    railties (5.2.4.4)
      actionpack (= 5.2.4.4)
      activesupport (= 5.2.4.4)
      method_source
      rake (>= 0.8.7)
      thor (>= 0.19.0, < 2.0)
    rake (13.0.1)
    rate_throttle_client (0.1.2)
    rb-fsevent (0.10.4)
    rb-inotify (0.10.1)
      ffi (~> 1.0)
    redis (4.0.3)
    redis-namespace (1.8.0)
      redis (>= 3.0.4)
    regexp_parser (1.8.0)
    representable (3.0.4)
      declarative (< 0.1.0)
      declarative-option (< 0.2.0)
      uber (< 0.2.0)
    request_store (1.5.0)
      rack (>= 1.4)
    rest-client (2.0.2)
      http-cookie (>= 1.0.2, < 2.0)
      mime-types (>= 1.16, < 4.0)
      netrc (~> 0.8)
    retriable (3.1.2)
    rexml (3.2.4)
    rspec-core (3.9.2)
      rspec-support (~> 3.9.3)
    rspec-expectations (3.9.2)
      diff-lcs (>= 1.2.0, < 2.0)
      rspec-support (~> 3.9.0)
    rspec-mocks (3.9.1)
      diff-lcs (>= 1.2.0, < 2.0)
      rspec-support (~> 3.9.0)
    rspec-rails (4.0.1)
      actionpack (>= 4.2)
      activesupport (>= 4.2)
      railties (>= 4.2)
      rspec-core (~> 3.9)
      rspec-expectations (~> 3.9)
      rspec-mocks (~> 3.9)
      rspec-support (~> 3.9)
    rspec-support (3.9.3)
    ruby2_keywords (0.0.2)
    scout_apm (4.0.0)
      parser
    secure_headers (6.3.1)
    shoulda-matchers (4.4.1)
      activesupport (>= 4.2.0)
    sidekiq (5.2.9)
      connection_pool (~> 2.2, >= 2.2.2)
      rack (~> 2.0)
      rack-protection (>= 1.5.0)
      redis (>= 3.3.5, < 4.2)
    signet (0.14.0)
      addressable (~> 2.3)
      faraday (>= 0.17.3, < 2.0)
      jwt (>= 1.5, < 3.0)
      multi_json (~> 1.10)
    simplecov (0.19.0)
      docile (~> 1.1)
      simplecov-html (~> 0.11)
    simplecov-html (0.12.2)
    sinatra (2.1.0)
      mustermann (~> 1.0)
      rack (~> 2.2)
      rack-protection (= 2.1.0)
      tilt (~> 2.0)
    spring (2.1.1)
    spring-watcher-listen (2.0.1)
      listen (>= 2.7, < 4.0)
      spring (>= 1.2, < 3.0)
    sprockets (4.0.2)
      concurrent-ruby (~> 1.0)
      rack (> 1, < 3)
    sprockets-rails (3.2.2)
      actionpack (>= 4.0)
      activesupport (>= 4.0)
      sprockets (>= 3.0.0)
    sys-uname (1.2.1)
      ffi (>= 1.0.0)
    thor (1.0.1)
    thread_safe (0.3.6)
    tilt (2.0.10)
    tzinfo (1.2.7)
      thread_safe (~> 0.1)
    tzinfo-data (1.2020.1)
      tzinfo (>= 1.0.0)
    uber (0.1.0)
    unf (0.1.4)
      unf_ext
    unf_ext (0.0.7.7)
    web-console (3.7.0)
      actionview (>= 5.0)
      activemodel (>= 5.0)
      bindex (>= 0.4.0)
      railties (>= 5.0)
    webmock (3.9.1)
      addressable (>= 2.3.6)
      crack (>= 0.3.2)
      hashdiff (>= 0.4.0, < 2.0.0)
    websocket-driver (0.7.3)
      websocket-extensions (>= 0.1.0)
    websocket-extensions (0.1.5)
    xpath (3.2.0)
      nokogiri (~> 1.8)

PLATFORMS
  ruby

DEPENDENCIES
  active_model_serializers (~> 0.10.10)
  bcrypt (~> 3.1.7)
  byebug
  capybara
  cucumber-rails
  database_cleaner
  factory_bot
  fcm
  google-cloud-storage
  honeybadger (~> 4.0)
  httparty
  listen (~> 3.0.5)
  lograge
  mailgun-ruby (~> 1.1.6)
  pg
  platform-api
  puma
  rack-cors
  rails (~> 5.2.4.4)
  rails-controller-testing
  redis (~> 4.0.2)
  redis-namespace
  rspec-rails
  scout_apm
  secure_headers
  shoulda-matchers
  sidekiq
  simplecov
  sinatra
  spring
  spring-watcher-listen (~> 2.0.0)
  tzinfo-data
  web-console
  webmock

RUBY VERSION
   ruby 2.6.6p146

BUNDLED WITH
   1.17.3
```

after running `bundle update`, Gemfile.lock becomes

```
GEM
  remote: http://rubygems.org/
  specs:
    actioncable (5.2.6)
      actionpack (= 5.2.6)
      nio4r (~> 2.0)
      websocket-driver (>= 0.6.1)
    actionmailer (5.2.6)
      actionpack (= 5.2.6)
      actionview (= 5.2.6)
      activejob (= 5.2.6)
      mail (~> 2.5, >= 2.5.4)
      rails-dom-testing (~> 2.0)
    actionpack (5.2.6)
      actionview (= 5.2.6)
      activesupport (= 5.2.6)
      rack (~> 2.0, >= 2.0.8)
      rack-test (>= 0.6.3)
      rails-dom-testing (~> 2.0)
      rails-html-sanitizer (~> 1.0, >= 1.0.2)
    actionview (5.2.6)
      activesupport (= 5.2.6)
      builder (~> 3.1)
      erubi (~> 1.4)
      rails-dom-testing (~> 2.0)
      rails-html-sanitizer (~> 1.0, >= 1.0.3)
    active_model_serializers (0.10.12)
      actionpack (>= 4.1, < 6.2)
      activemodel (>= 4.1, < 6.2)
      case_transform (>= 0.2)
      jsonapi-renderer (>= 0.1.1.beta1, < 0.3)
    activejob (5.2.6)
      activesupport (= 5.2.6)
      globalid (>= 0.3.6)
    activemodel (5.2.6)
      activesupport (= 5.2.6)
    activerecord (5.2.6)
      activemodel (= 5.2.6)
      activesupport (= 5.2.6)
      arel (>= 9.0)
    activestorage (5.2.6)
      actionpack (= 5.2.6)
      activerecord (= 5.2.6)
      marcel (~> 1.0.0)
    activesupport (5.2.6)
      concurrent-ruby (~> 1.0, >= 1.0.2)
      i18n (>= 0.7, < 2)
      minitest (~> 5.1)
      tzinfo (~> 1.1)
    addressable (2.8.0)
      public_suffix (>= 2.0.2, < 5.0)
    arel (9.0.0)
    ast (2.4.2)
    bcrypt (3.1.16)
    bindex (0.8.1)
    builder (3.2.4)
    byebug (11.1.3)
    capybara (3.36.0)
      addressable
      matrix
      mini_mime (>= 0.1.3)
      nokogiri (~> 1.8)
      rack (>= 1.6.0)
      rack-test (>= 0.6.3)
      regexp_parser (>= 1.5, < 3.0)
      xpath (~> 3.2)
    case_transform (0.2)
      activesupport
    concurrent-ruby (1.1.9)
    connection_pool (2.2.5)
    crack (0.4.5)
      rexml
    crass (1.0.6)
    cucumber (7.1.0)
      builder (~> 3.2, >= 3.2.4)
      cucumber-core (~> 10.1, >= 10.1.0)
      cucumber-create-meta (~> 6.0, >= 6.0.1)
      cucumber-cucumber-expressions (~> 14.0, >= 14.0.0)
      cucumber-gherkin (~> 22.0, >= 22.0.0)
      cucumber-html-formatter (~> 17.0, >= 17.0.0)
      cucumber-messages (~> 17.1, >= 17.1.1)
      cucumber-wire (~> 6.2, >= 6.2.0)
      diff-lcs (~> 1.4, >= 1.4.4)
      mime-types (~> 3.3, >= 3.3.1)
      multi_test (~> 0.1, >= 0.1.2)
      sys-uname (~> 1.2, >= 1.2.2)
    cucumber-core (10.1.0)
      cucumber-gherkin (~> 22.0, >= 22.0.0)
      cucumber-messages (~> 17.1, >= 17.1.1)
      cucumber-tag-expressions (~> 4.0, >= 4.0.2)
    cucumber-create-meta (6.0.2)
      cucumber-messages (~> 17.1, >= 17.1.1)
      sys-uname (~> 1.2, >= 1.2.2)
    cucumber-cucumber-expressions (14.0.0)
    cucumber-gherkin (22.0.0)
      cucumber-messages (~> 17.1, >= 17.1.1)
    cucumber-html-formatter (17.0.0)
      cucumber-messages (~> 17.1, >= 17.1.0)
    cucumber-messages (17.1.1)
    cucumber-rails (2.4.0)
      capybara (>= 2.18, < 4)
      cucumber (>= 3.2, < 8)
      mime-types (~> 3.3)
      nokogiri (~> 1.10)
      railties (>= 5.0, < 7)
      rexml (~> 3.0)
      webrick (~> 1.7)
    cucumber-tag-expressions (4.1.0)
    cucumber-wire (6.2.0)
      cucumber-core (~> 10.1, >= 10.1.0)
      cucumber-cucumber-expressions (~> 14.0, >= 14.0.0)
      cucumber-messages (~> 17.1, >= 17.1.1)
    database_cleaner (2.0.1)
      database_cleaner-active_record (~> 2.0.0)
    database_cleaner-active_record (2.0.1)
      activerecord (>= 5.a)
      database_cleaner-core (~> 2.0.0)
    database_cleaner-core (2.0.1)
    declarative (0.0.20)
    diff-lcs (1.4.4)
    digest-crc (0.6.4)
      rake (>= 12.0.0, < 14.0.0)
    docile (1.4.0)
    domain_name (0.5.20190701)
      unf (>= 0.0.5, < 1.0.0)
    erubi (1.10.0)
    erubis (2.7.0)
    excon (0.88.0)
    factory_bot (6.2.0)
      activesupport (>= 5.0.0)
    faraday (1.8.0)
      faraday-em_http (~> 1.0)
      faraday-em_synchrony (~> 1.0)
      faraday-excon (~> 1.1)
      faraday-httpclient (~> 1.0.1)
      faraday-net_http (~> 1.0)
      faraday-net_http_persistent (~> 1.1)
      faraday-patron (~> 1.0)
      faraday-rack (~> 1.0)
      multipart-post (>= 1.2, < 3)
      ruby2_keywords (>= 0.0.4)
    faraday-em_http (1.0.0)
    faraday-em_synchrony (1.0.0)
    faraday-excon (1.1.0)
    faraday-httpclient (1.0.1)
    faraday-net_http (1.0.1)
    faraday-net_http_persistent (1.2.0)
    faraday-patron (1.0.0)
    faraday-rack (1.0.0)
    fcm (1.0.3)
      faraday (~> 1)
    ffi (1.15.4)
    get_process_mem (0.2.7)
      ffi (~> 1.0)
    globalid (0.5.2)
      activesupport (>= 5.0)
    google-apis-core (0.4.1)
      addressable (~> 2.5, >= 2.5.1)
      googleauth (>= 0.16.2, < 2.a)
      httpclient (>= 2.8.1, < 3.a)
      mini_mime (~> 1.0)
      representable (~> 3.0)
      retriable (>= 2.0, < 4.a)
      rexml
      webrick
    google-apis-iamcredentials_v1 (0.8.0)
      google-apis-core (>= 0.4, < 2.a)
    google-apis-storage_v1 (0.9.0)
      google-apis-core (>= 0.4, < 2.a)
    google-cloud-core (1.6.0)
      google-cloud-env (~> 1.0)
      google-cloud-errors (~> 1.0)
    google-cloud-env (1.5.0)
      faraday (>= 0.17.3, < 2.0)
    google-cloud-errors (1.2.0)
    google-cloud-storage (1.34.1)
      addressable (~> 2.5)
      digest-crc (~> 0.4)
      google-apis-iamcredentials_v1 (~> 0.1)
      google-apis-storage_v1 (~> 0.1)
      google-cloud-core (~> 1.6)
      googleauth (>= 0.16.2, < 2.a)
      mini_mime (~> 1.0)
    googleauth (1.1.0)
      faraday (>= 0.17.3, < 2.0)
      jwt (>= 1.4, < 3.0)
      memoist (~> 0.16)
      multi_json (~> 1.11)
      os (>= 0.9, < 2.0)
      signet (>= 0.16, < 2.a)
    hashdiff (1.0.1)
    heroics (0.1.2)
      erubis (~> 2.0)
      excon
      moneta
      multi_json (>= 1.9.2)
      webrick
    honeybadger (4.9.0)
    http-cookie (1.0.4)
      domain_name (~> 0.5)
    httparty (0.20.0)
      mime-types (~> 3.0)
      multi_xml (>= 0.5.2)
    httpclient (2.8.3)
    i18n (1.8.10)
      concurrent-ruby (~> 1.0)
    jsonapi-renderer (0.2.2)
    jwt (2.3.0)
    listen (3.0.8)
      rb-fsevent (~> 0.9, >= 0.9.4)
      rb-inotify (~> 0.9, >= 0.9.7)
    lograge (0.11.2)
      actionpack (>= 4)
      activesupport (>= 4)
      railties (>= 4)
      request_store (~> 1.0)
    loofah (2.12.0)
      crass (~> 1.0.2)
      nokogiri (>= 1.5.9)
    mail (2.7.1)
      mini_mime (>= 0.1.1)
    mailgun-ruby (1.1.11)
      rest-client (~> 2.0.2)
    marcel (1.0.2)
    matrix (0.4.2)
    memoist (0.16.2)
    method_source (1.0.0)
    mime-types (3.3.1)
      mime-types-data (~> 3.2015)
    mime-types-data (3.2021.0901)
    mini_mime (1.1.2)
    mini_portile2 (2.6.1)
    minitest (5.14.4)
    moneta (1.0.0)
    multi_json (1.15.0)
    multi_test (0.1.2)
    multi_xml (0.6.0)
    multipart-post (2.1.1)
    mustermann (1.1.1)
      ruby2_keywords (~> 0.0.1)
    netrc (0.11.0)
    nio4r (2.5.8)
    nokogiri (1.12.5)
      mini_portile2 (~> 2.6.1)
      racc (~> 1.4)
    os (1.1.1)
    parser (3.0.2.0)
      ast (~> 2.4.1)
    pg (1.2.3)
    platform-api (3.3.0)
      heroics (~> 0.1.1)
      moneta (~> 1.0.0)
      rate_throttle_client (~> 0.1.0)
    public_suffix (4.0.6)
    puma (5.5.2)
      nio4r (~> 2.0)
    puma_worker_killer (0.3.1)
      get_process_mem (~> 0.2)
      puma (>= 2.7)
    racc (1.6.0)
    rack (2.2.3)
    rack-cors (1.1.1)
      rack (>= 2.0.0)
    rack-protection (2.1.0)
      rack
    rack-test (1.1.0)
      rack (>= 1.0, < 3)
    rails (5.2.6)
      actioncable (= 5.2.6)
      actionmailer (= 5.2.6)
      actionpack (= 5.2.6)
      actionview (= 5.2.6)
      activejob (= 5.2.6)
      activemodel (= 5.2.6)
      activerecord (= 5.2.6)
      activestorage (= 5.2.6)
      activesupport (= 5.2.6)
      bundler (>= 1.3.0)
      railties (= 5.2.6)
      sprockets-rails (>= 2.0.0)
    rails-controller-testing (1.0.5)
      actionpack (>= 5.0.1.rc1)
      actionview (>= 5.0.1.rc1)
      activesupport (>= 5.0.1.rc1)
    rails-dom-testing (2.0.3)
      activesupport (>= 4.2.0)
      nokogiri (>= 1.6)
    rails-html-sanitizer (1.4.2)
      loofah (~> 2.3)
    railties (5.2.6)
      actionpack (= 5.2.6)
      activesupport (= 5.2.6)
      method_source
      rake (>= 0.8.7)
      thor (>= 0.19.0, < 2.0)
    rake (13.0.6)
    rate_throttle_client (0.1.2)
    rb-fsevent (0.11.0)
    rb-inotify (0.10.1)
      ffi (~> 1.0)
    redis (4.0.3)
    redis-namespace (1.8.1)
      redis (>= 3.0.4)
    regexp_parser (2.1.1)
    representable (3.1.1)
      declarative (< 0.1.0)
      trailblazer-option (>= 0.1.1, < 0.2.0)
      uber (< 0.2.0)
    request_store (1.5.0)
      rack (>= 1.4)
    rest-client (2.0.2)
      http-cookie (>= 1.0.2, < 2.0)
      mime-types (>= 1.16, < 4.0)
      netrc (~> 0.8)
    retriable (3.1.2)
    rexml (3.2.5)
    rspec-core (3.10.1)
      rspec-support (~> 3.10.0)
    rspec-expectations (3.10.1)
      diff-lcs (>= 1.2.0, < 2.0)
      rspec-support (~> 3.10.0)
    rspec-mocks (3.10.2)
      diff-lcs (>= 1.2.0, < 2.0)
      rspec-support (~> 3.10.0)
    rspec-rails (5.0.2)
      actionpack (>= 5.2)
      activesupport (>= 5.2)
      railties (>= 5.2)
      rspec-core (~> 3.10)
      rspec-expectations (~> 3.10)
      rspec-mocks (~> 3.10)
      rspec-support (~> 3.10)
    rspec-support (3.10.2)
    ruby2_keywords (0.0.5)
    scout_apm (4.1.2)
      parser
    secure_headers (6.3.3)
    shoulda-matchers (5.0.0)
      activesupport (>= 5.2.0)
    sidekiq (5.2.9)
      connection_pool (~> 2.2, >= 2.2.2)
      rack (~> 2.0)
      rack-protection (>= 1.5.0)
      redis (>= 3.3.5, < 4.2)
    signet (0.16.0)
      addressable (~> 2.8)
      faraday (>= 0.17.3, < 2.0)
      jwt (>= 1.5, < 3.0)
      multi_json (~> 1.10)
    simplecov (0.21.2)
      docile (~> 1.1)
      simplecov-html (~> 0.11)
      simplecov_json_formatter (~> 0.1)
    simplecov-html (0.12.3)
    simplecov_json_formatter (0.1.3)
    sinatra (2.1.0)
      mustermann (~> 1.0)
      rack (~> 2.2)
      rack-protection (= 2.1.0)
      tilt (~> 2.0)
    spring (2.1.1)
    spring-watcher-listen (2.0.1)
      listen (>= 2.7, < 4.0)
      spring (>= 1.2, < 3.0)
    sprockets (4.0.2)
      concurrent-ruby (~> 1.0)
      rack (> 1, < 3)
    sprockets-rails (3.2.2)
      actionpack (>= 4.0)
      activesupport (>= 4.0)
      sprockets (>= 3.0.0)
    sys-uname (1.2.2)
      ffi (~> 1.1)
    thor (1.1.0)
    thread_safe (0.3.6)
    tilt (2.0.10)
    trailblazer-option (0.1.1)
    tzinfo (1.2.9)
      thread_safe (~> 0.1)
    tzinfo-data (1.2021.5)
      tzinfo (>= 1.0.0)
    uber (0.1.0)
    unf (0.1.4)
      unf_ext
    unf_ext (0.0.8)
    web-console (3.7.0)
      actionview (>= 5.0)
      activemodel (>= 5.0)
      bindex (>= 0.4.0)
      railties (>= 5.0)
    webmock (3.14.0)
      addressable (>= 2.8.0)
      crack (>= 0.3.2)
      hashdiff (>= 0.4.0, < 2.0.0)
    webrick (1.7.0)
    websocket-driver (0.7.5)
      websocket-extensions (>= 0.1.0)
    websocket-extensions (0.1.5)
    xpath (3.2.0)
      nokogiri (~> 1.8)

PLATFORMS
  ruby

DEPENDENCIES
  active_model_serializers (~> 0.10.10)
  bcrypt (~> 3.1.7)
  byebug
  capybara
  cucumber-rails
  database_cleaner
  factory_bot
  fcm
  google-cloud-storage
  honeybadger (~> 4.0)
  httparty
  listen (~> 3.0.5)
  lograge
  mailgun-ruby (~> 1.1.6)
  pg
  platform-api
  puma
  puma_worker_killer
  rack-cors
  rails (~> 5.2.5)
  rails-controller-testing
  redis (~> 4.0.2)
  redis-namespace
  rspec-rails
  scout_apm
  secure_headers
  shoulda-matchers
  sidekiq
  simplecov
  sinatra
  spring
  spring-watcher-listen (~> 2.0.0)
  tzinfo-data
  web-console
  webmock

RUBY VERSION
   ruby 2.6.6p146

BUNDLED WITH
   1.17.3
```

Bundler version is `Bundler version 1.17.2 (2018-12-19 commit 3fc4de72b)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The specifier `~>` has a special meaning. `~> 5.2.5` is identical to `>= 5.2.5` and `< 5.3`. At the time writing this, the latest version `< 5.3` is `5.2.6`.

If you want exactly version `5.2.5` you should write `gem 'rails', '5.2.5'`.